# How to get members of multiple Azure AD groups recursively in a fast way via Azure AD API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, active-directory-group

I get groups via

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.6
```

Then get all members in some groups that I'm interested in via

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{group_obj_id}/members?api-version=1.6
```

If there are some groups in some group, I recursively get members in that group.

But if I want to extract members of 5 groups and suppose there is 1 group in each group, then 10 different groups in total. One API call sometimes cost about 1s. Then I need to call 10 times, then I need to wait 10 sec!

Does anyone have a faster way to get members in multiple groups (with/without group -in-group)?

Comment: That is the only way to do it. Remember to do some circular reference checking, because Group A may be a member of Group B, and Group B may be a member of Group C, which can be a member of Group A, etc.

Comment: What scenario are you trying to achieve by getting all members of a group (including expanding nested groups)?  There could be other alternatives...

Comment: Given a user id, and a list of groups, decide whether the user is in the group list or not. I hope there are other alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

At present, the Azure AD Graph REST doesn't support to retrieve the members of a group recursively. We have to get group members level by level.

If you want Azure AD Graph to support this feature, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).